# Hibernate loading all entities utilizing 1st or 2nd level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, caching, ehcache

We have an entire table of entities that we need to load during a hibernate session and the only way I know to load all entities is through an HQL query:

```
public <T> List<T> getAllEntities(final Class<T> entityClass) {
    if (null == entityClass)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("entityClass can't be null");

    List<T> list = castResultList(createQuery(
            "select e from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " e ").list());


    return list;
}
```

We use EHcache for 2nd level caching.

The problem is this gets called 100's of times in a given transaction session and takes up a considerable portion of the total time. Is there any way to load all entities of a given type (load an entire table) and still benefit from 1st level session cache or 2nd level ehcache.

We've been told to stay away from query caching because of their potential performance penalties relative to their gains.
 * [Hibernate Query Cache considered harmful](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/)

Although we're doing performance profiling right now so it might be time to try turning on query cache.

Comment: Why is your code reloading the entire table 100s of times in the same transaction in the first place?  If it's because other threads may be doing inserts, then neither the L1 nor the L2 cache can do too much to help you even if you do rewrite the code in some arcane way to use them.

Comment: It's a static table (at least static each 24 hours) it's more that, the method is called 100's of times in a given transacation, we could easily "cache" that method for that transaction in our DAO, but I was curious if I was reinventing caching that was already done if I loaded the table differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up solving this by storing in memory the primary keys to all the entities in the table we needed to load (because they're template data and no new templates are added/removed).

Then we could use this list of primary keys to look up each entity and utilize Hibernates 1st and 2nd level cache.

Answer (score 1):

L1 and L2 cache can't help you much with the problem of "get an entire table."

The L1 cache is ill-equipped because if someone else inserted something, it's not there.    (You may "know" that no one else would ever do so within the business rules of the system, but the Hibernate Session doesn't.)  Hence you have to go look in the DB to be sure.

With the L2 cache, things may have been expired or flushed since the last time anybody put the table in there.  This can be at the mercy of the cache provider or even done totally externally, maybe through a MBean.  So Hibernate can't really know at any given time if what's in the cache for that type represents the entire contents of the table.  Again, you have to look in the DB to be sure.

Since you have special knowledge about this Entity (new ones are never created) that there isn't a practical way to impart on the L1 or L2 caches, you need to either use the tool provided by Hibernate for when you have special business-rules-level knowledge about a result set, query cache, or cache the info yourself.

--

If you really really want it in the L2 cache, you could in theory make all entities in the table members of a collection on some other bogus entity, then enable caching the collection and manage it secretly in the DAO.  I don't think it could possibly be worth having that kind of bizarreness in your code though :)

Answer (score 1):

Query cache is considered harmful if and only if the underlying table changes often. In your case the table is changed once a day. So the query would stay in cache for 24 hours. Trust me: use the query cache for it. It is a perfect use case for a query cache.

Example of harmful query cache: if you have a user table and you use the query cache for "from User where username = ..." then this query will evict from cache each time the user table is modified (another user changes/deletes his account). So ANY modification of this table triggers cache eviction. The only way to improve this situation is querying by natural-id, but this is another story.

If you know your table will be modified only once a day as in your case, the query cache will only evict once a day!

But pay attention on your logic when modifying the table. If you do it via hibernate everything is fine. If you use a direct query you have to tell hibernate that you have modified the table (something like query.addSynchronizedEntity(..)). If you do it via shell script you need to adjust the time-to-live of the underlying cache region.

Your answer is by the way reimplementing the query cache as the query cache just caches the list of ids. The actual objects are looked up in L1/L2 cache. so you still need to cache the entities when you use the query cache.

Please mark this as the correct answer for further reference.