# cache entire table with NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, caching

Is there a way to tell NHibernate (2.0) that an entire table always has to be kept in the 2nd level cache? Or is there a way to intercept a cache miss, or when NHibernate is trying to load a single entity and redirect that query to load the entire table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to create a custom Get function instead of session.Get(). First get an IEntityPersister: session.GetSessionImplementation().GetEntityPersister(new T()). Ugly, because there's no overload with a Type parameter, but works. Then we can get the cache, and check if the entity is in the cache. If it's not, then load all the elements from the database. This way, when using this custom Get function, NHibernate will never load the entities one by one, but all at once, and it will cache them, until it expires, then load them again the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would be to enable 2nd level caching on that entity, and on application start, to execute a query which would load all of them.
It doesn't *guarantee* that it'll always be there (cache can be flushed / removed for many reasons), but it might be good enough for you.

Alternatively- you can implement such a thing yourself quite simply by utilizing System.Cache

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this other [post on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613692/hibernate-loading-all-entities-utilizing-1st-or-2nd-level-cache)? OK its hibernate but I suspect you can apply the same principals to NHibernate.

> We ended up solving this by storing in
>   memory the primary keys to all the
>   entities in the table we needed to
>   load (because they're template data
>   and no new templates are
>   added/removed).
>
> Then we could use this list of primary
>   keys to look up each entity and
>   utilize Hibernates 1st and 2nd level
>   cache.